# R package Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘reshape2’ in loadNamespace: there is no package called ‘magrittr’

Tags: r, reshape2, r-package

I have installed `install.packages("reshape2")` on R 3.4.3

but when I try to use that library like

```
library(reshape2)
```

I get the below error

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘reshape2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> there is no package called ‘magrittr’
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘reshape2’ was built under R version 3.4.4**

But I want reshape2 to run on R 3.4.3 only

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try install.packages("magrittr") as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by the below command:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/magrittr/magrittr_1.5.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```